# Finding string in another string

Tags: php, string

I have a string like this: `$str1 = "mod 1 + mode 2 + comp 1 + toto"`.

I would like to test if `mod 1` is in `$str1`. I used `strpos` but this function doesn't help.

Comment: But `"mod 1 + mode 2 + comp 1 + toto"` really does not contain `" mod 1"` (note the spaces).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`strpos`](http://php.net/strpos) returns the position of the occurrence in the string starting with 0 or *false* otherwise. Using just a boolean conversion like in the following is a common mistake:

```
$str1 = "mod 1 + mode 2 + comp 1 + toto";
if (strpos($str, "mod 1")) {
    // found
}
```

Because in this case `strpos` will return 0. But 0 converted to Boolean is *false*:

```
var_dump((bool) 0 === false);  // bool(true)
```

So you need to use a strict comparison:

```
$str1 = "mod 1 + mode 2 + comp 1 + toto";
if (strpos($str, "mod 1") !== false) {
    // found
}
```

This is also what the documentation advises:

> **Warning** This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE, such as 0 or "". Please read the section on [Booleans](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) for more information. Use the [`===` operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) for testing the return value of this function.

Comment: Yes I see, but the use of this , always return false ! 
I am gonna try again and will post
thank u guys

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the [strstr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) function.

```
$str1 = "mod 1 + mode 2 + comp 1 + toto";
$str2 = "mod 1";

if(strstr($str1,$str2) !== false)
 echo "Found $str2 in $str1\n";
```

Comment: @Mamadou: This code works, but you should go through `Gumbo's` answer and try to understand why the `strpos` you tried did not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(stripos($str,'mod 1')!==false) $hasmod1 = true;
else $hasmod1 = false;
```

Care for the `!==` this is the important part.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php